# Only property getter methods are allowed to have Java Persistence annotations such as @Transient

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, netbeans, transient

I have a entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class AquilesZamora extends EntitySuperClass
{
     fields setters and getters omit for brevity
     @javax.persistence.Transient
     public AquilesZamora loadIdC03AndC08(final Integer id,final Integer c03,final Integer c08){super.setId(id);this.c03=c03;this.c08=c08;return this;}
}
```

I have several `@Transient` methods in my model but I code this method and says.

> Only property getter methods are allowed to have Java Persistence annotations such as @Transient.

This is strange and if I use it in Eclipse compiles fine what this method wrong with Netbeans.

My environment is:

Netbeans 8.2, Java 8 update 40, Eclipse Kepler, Hibernate 4.1.6.

[image: Netbeans Error]

Answer (score 0):

transient is only for fields

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object.

so it's good for get but not for other methods (how could be?)